# Smart watch capable of receiveing calls from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, accessories

Are there any "smart" watches *(smart being like the Pebble, I'm watch, Martian  ...)* that supports the following capabilities for an iPhone?

- Receiving or answering a call
- Rejecting a call

Comment: Are you looking for something technical here or is this just a "shopping" question where you seek a list of products that are commercially available that fit your criteria? Any bluetooth device with handsfree functionality, speaker, mic and a button clearly will allow calls to be answered.

Comment: As I have seen many watches supporting Android, I am looking for some technical details and I also would like to know about the product with these features.

Comment: AFAIK Pebble will only show you who is calling, but you can't answer or reject the call from the watch

Comment: If you found a solution to your question please add it as answer below (and rollback your edit to the question) to keep the site in Q&A format. There might be other answers in the future as well and it will just confuse people if one answer is already included in the question.

Comment: @ Dirty-flow :Using Pebble you can accept the call but you should have another HFP device to proceed further as pebble does not have inbuilt speaker and microphone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pebble( on other HFP device like carkit or headphone) and I'm watch,Maritan Watch (built in microphone and speaker) are capable of receiving or answering calls.

http://help.getpebble.com/customer/portal/articles/957384-pebble-user-guide

http://martianwatches.com/products/

http://www.imsmart.com/en/i-m-watch/specifications

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have a Pebble and it has the ability to answer and reject calls from iPhone (5). However, without a built in speaker and mic, you can't use it for talking...

And, unfortunately, it doesn't force the call through the handsfree :(

Answer (score 0):

The [Apple Watch](https://www.apple.com/watch/apple-watch/), which will be released early 2015.